# Need to update Chrome extension to manifest version 2 if no manifest version originally specified?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest

My extension currently doesn't specify any manifest version. Does it need to be updated to manifest version 2?

It's a bit unclear, based on these pages (perhaps need to be updated for clarity):

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html mentions policy change from version 1 to 2 about this:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

particularly this excerpt of text:

"Packages that do not define a manifest_version have no default content security policy. Those that select manifest_version 2, have a default content security policy of:
script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'
This policy adds security by limiting extensions and applications in two ways..."

And I did get an email from Google about the need to update from manifest version 1 to 2, though assume that may have been a general email to all extension developers that have published to their store.

I could update my extension, unfortunately, I use inline javascript and it would be a bit of a hassle to modify the code for the new design change. Since I don't specify a manifest version to begin with, would rather not update if I didn't have to.

On a side note, would be nice if Google had a way to determine if app broke in compatibility when you change manifest versions. My app w/o code update, adding manifest version 2 and loading in Chrome would install fine but would fail to load/popup because of the content security policy, which I figured from reading the docs. Would have been better if it failed to install because it didn't meet policy, easier to debug that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it.
Mo manifest_version equals to version 1.

Quote:
"Extensions, applications, and themes that aren't ready to make the jump to the new manifest version in Chrome 18 can either explicitly specify version 1, **or leave the key off** entirely."

From:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#manifest_version

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that as an answer unless someone can tell otherwise why I don't need to update. Now I have to spend the hassle to make my javascript "proper". :(

Comment: Yes, I know.  I'm delaying the update untill my old extensions stop working!