# Chrome's webstore server reject an extension with "Error : The manifest must define a version."

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

NOTE: this question is about the `version` attribute of the `manifest.json` that you use when you do Chrome developpment. It looks similar with the question below about `manifest_version` but it's not. I really tried to learn from that but I failed.

[Need to update Chrome extension to manifest version 2 if no manifest version originally specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418979/need-to-update-chrome-extension-to-manifest-version-2-if-no-manifest-version-ori)

--

I am currently doing my first Chrome extension. Powerful, fun, great.

Except a stupid thing that keeps annoying me.

My Chrome extension is open-source, so you can go straight to the code on GitHub so you can see in an instant that I made a stupid mistake

https://github.com/internaciulo/search-tab-in-chrome-s-omnibox

In `manifest.json`, the most imortant file in Chrome development, you should see

```
{
  ...
  "version": "13",
  ...
}
```

The chrome extension itself works well enough, see the screenshots folder on github, ... but only *locally*, that is when I open it as an unpackage app (this can be done in Chrome by going into `chrome://extensions`

Great, so I head up to [Chrome's Webstore Developer Dashbord], upload, let 2 or 3 users download it for free, Profit !

---

Not quite.

I tried everything : maybe he wants `13`or `"13"` or "13.0" or there is a confusion with `manifest_version` which must be an integer or or or or. Every time the same annoying error :

> Upload an extension or app (.zip file)
>   search-tab-in-chrome-s-omnibox.zip (Server rejected)
>   An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
>
> The manifest must define a version.

Oh Computers, you are so useful, but why are so intolerants to our mistakes dear computer ? Yes, they are stupid, but since the beginning of Computing, you should have learned that we are *"Humans, All Too Humans"* (`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human,_All_Too_Human`)

PS: it's not only my first chrome extension, it's also my first question on stackoverflow, while I used it a lost in the past, but only read-only. Please be nice :-D

**Updates:**

- 2013-10-13 : ok, problem solved, this was it : **no comments in json files**
- 2013-10-13 : A part (only) of the bug is resolved thanks to @ChrisP: comments are not allowed in json files, which is sad but legitimate. https://github.com/getify/JSON.minify allows you to take json file with comments and output it minified without comments. Best of both worlds.

Comment: Your manifest is not valid JSON. Remove all the comments, which are not allowed, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Weird but true but legitimate but not enough to solve the bug. See my new commit on my github.

By the way, if I understand correctly, I can't approve your future answer if it's only here :)

Comment: OK, I'll add a proper answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `manifest.json` file contains comments:

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_name__", // {en}: "Search Tab in Chrome's Omnibox" 
  "description": "__MSG_description__",
  ...
}
```

which are not allowed in JSON, cf http://json.org/.

If you remove them, your manifest should be valid, and the error should disappear.
You can find JSON parsers online to ensure it's valid, for example:

- http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
- http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Thank you ChrisP, this is definitely a necessary step to let Google's servers accept my little Chrome extension.

Alas, this step is not sufficient, because after reading your comments and a thread dedicated to comments in JSON on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-i-comment-a-json-file) 

I have now removed the comments and Google's server keeps telling me the same error : **The manifest must define a version**

I have updated my github repository
https://github.com/internaciulo/search-tab-in-chrome-s-omnibox

Comment: That's very weird, I used the 'Download ZIP' link of your GitHub repository, and was able to successfully publish the extension. How do you compress your extension?

Comment: with git...
    git archive --format zip --output "../search-tab-in-chrome-s-omnibox.zip" master -0

well well, I found it, I did correct the bug according to your response.
but since I tried many things to resolve this stupid bug before, including trying to publish it on another name, I had two *zip file that look the same in the same directory, and of course I chose the wrong one :'(

    $ ls ../*zip`
    ../search-tab-in-chrome-s-omnibox.zip        
    ../search-your-tabs-with-the-tab-keyword.zip

Comment: *I have a dream, that one day, computers understand how stupid we are :-)*

Any way : THANKS A LOT :-D